# Getting target=_blank to work with images that have anchors in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not sure how to add the target=_blank to my code below. I am using Codeigniter and my image below contains an external link and works like a charm. I would love to have it open in a new window or tab but I'm unsure how to do it. I haven't found anything so far of anyone else using this method. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

```
<?php
echo anchor(
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    img(array(
        'src'=>base_url().'images/facebook.png',
        'width'=>'32',
        'height'=>'32',
        'id'=>'facebook',
        'alt'=>'Facebook Logo'
    ))
);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Err, pass the attribute as the third argument to `anchor()`

```
<?php
echo anchor(
    'http://www.facebook.com/artisticconcretegroup',
    img(array(
        'src'=>base_url().'images/facebook.png',
        'width'=>'32',
        'height'=>'32',
        'id'=>'facebook',
        'alt'=>'Facebook Logo'
    )),
    ['target' => '_blank'] // or array('target' => '_blank') if PHP < 5.4
);?>
```

Or even more simply, use the code you have but with the `anchor_popup()` function.

It's all in the docs - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Or even simpler: don't even use PHP to write HTML. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Phil! I've been reading the docs for the past hour or so with no luck.

Comment: @Shomz I totally agree

Answer (score 0):

simply add `'target="_blank"'`

eg. `echo anchor("url",'click here','target="_blank"')`

Comment: last param is just additional html attributes in string format that will be append to a tag along with href tag